# angular-isotope image overlap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, imagesloaded

I'm using **[angular-isotope](https://github.com/mankindsoftware/angular-isotope)** in my homepage to organize my items but sometimes it overlap my images...

To fix it I know I should use **imagesLoaded** and when I used Isotope with jQuery it was pretty easy to implement but now I'm using it with **AngularJS** how can I add it?

I tried to modify a bit the directive but I still don't have the knowledge to do it properly and I received tons of errors or it didn't worked at all...

I also found **[angular-images-loaded](https://github.com/homerjam/angular-images-loaded)** but I can not understand how to implement it to work with **angular-isotope**.

I'm pretty sure someone already had this kind of problem but I didn't found any Question related to this argument here or Googleling around.

A link to a tutorial or a small piece of code would be appreciated to understand how to fix / implement it.

Comment: Can you give some plunkr? We can't help you without further knowledge of this problem.

Comment: About what? It is an implementation between two different directives... Simply looking at the angular-isotope on GitHub you can see how does it work... I need to apply imagesLoaded before isotope init.

Comment: I asked you for an example, because I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve by merging functionality of those directives (there are so many configurations). 
Please, give some drawing, print-screen, plunkr, whatever, but be precise how the result should looked like.

Comment: If you used isotope with jQuery most of the time you need to use imagesLoaded on the images container before using isotope... this fix the image overlapping... With angularJS I don't know how to run imagesLoaded before Isotope because it attach the isotope directive directly to the container in the HTML. So I think there is away/solution to fix this issue...